# Scala match function against variable

Tags: scala, jvm, pattern-matching

When I'm matching value of case classes, such as:

```
sealed abstract class Op
case class UOp[T, K](f: T => K) extends Op
case class BOp[T, Z, K](f: (T, Z) => K) extends Op
```

like this:

```
def f(op: Op): Int =
op match
{
    case BOp(g) => g(1,2)
    case UOp(g) => g(0)
}
```

the compiler infers it as

```
val g: (Nothing, Nothing) => Any
val g: Nothing => Any
```

Why am I getting Nothing as the type? Is it because of JVM type erasure? Are there elegant ways to match functions against variables?

Comment: If you remove the type parameters from `UOp` and `BOp` and replace `T, Z, K` with `Int` then you will be fine. The problem with your code is that there is nothing preventing an instance of `UOp(Long, String, Double)` from being passed to `f`. Without knowing more about your goal and what is acceptable and not, it'S difficult to suggest an alternative.

Comment: How do the arguments look like in real application? Can you say that you have `TupleN` args that you want to match to a function that takes this number of arguments?

Comment: @drstevens @aleksey-izmailov I realized, that I have to define functions with exact types. Just  coding kinda arithmetic interpreter, so it's enough to deal with Doubles. But how to extend OP classes to work with Ints, Floats etc?    
 `case class BinaryOp[T <% Ordered[T], Z <% Ordered[Z], K <% Ordered[K]](f: (T, Z) => K) extends Op
 case class UnaryOp[T <% Ordered[T], K <% Ordered[K]](f: (T) => K) extends Op`   don't compiles anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this "hackish" solution, maybe there are other ways or cleaner ways to do this still without relying on reflection.

Define a few partial functions which will handle various args:

```
scala> val f: PartialFunction[Any, String] = { case (x: Int, y: String) => y * x }
f: PartialFunction[Any,String] = <function1>

scala> val g: PartialFunction[Any, String] = { case x: Int => x.toString }
g: PartialFunction[Any,String] = <function1>

scala> def h: PartialFunction[Any, BigDecimal] = { case (a: Int, b: Double, c: Long) => BigDecimal(a) + b + c }
h: PartialFunction[Any,BigDecimal]

scala> val l: List[PartialFunction[Any, Any]] = f :: g :: h :: Nil
l: List[PartialFunction[Any,Any]] = List(<function1>, <function1>, <function1>)
```

Check which functions can handle different inputs:

```
scala> l.map(_.isDefinedAt(1))
res0: List[Boolean] = List(false, true, false)

scala> l.map(_.isDefinedAt((1, "one")))
res1: List[Boolean] = List(true, false, false)
```

Given input find and apply a function:

```
scala> def applyFunction(input: Any): Option[Any] = {
     |   l find (_.isDefinedAt(input)) map (_ (input))
     | }
applyFunction: (input: Any)Option[Any]

scala> applyFunction(1)
res1: Option[Any] = Some(1)

scala> applyFunction((2, "one"))
res2: Option[Any] = Some(oneone)

scala> applyFunction("one")
res3: Option[Any] = None

scala> applyFunction(1, 1.1, 9L)
res10: Option[Any] = Some(11.1)
```

This looks quite type unsafe and there must be better ways to do this.

I think magnet pattern should handle this well in more typesafe manner.